# Problem when initialize quartz bean in spring boot using h2

Tags: spring-boot, h2, liquibase

I tried to configure spring quartz in one of my project. When I run it against Oracle database it works like charm. However running it against H2 database I got error

```
Function "EMPTY_BLOB" not found
```

It happens when quartzScheduler bean is initialized.

my configuration is:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto: update
spring.database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

I don't know where I can find solution and google is no help in this case.

I use liquibase. H2 version is 1.4.200 and spring boot version is 2.2.5.RELEASE.

I notice that changing ddl.auto to create or create-drop will cause different type of error, it will complain about my table I created using mysql. Also, when I change it to **validate** compiler complains about wrong number type "found Decimal but expecting BigInt".